# Including a local tar.gz file in setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

Is there a way to reference local tar.gz files in 'install_requires' in the setup.py? I have a file at e.g. C:/mymodules/mydependency/mydependency.tar.gz. How should I include this in the setup file? I have tried:

```
setup(
name="mymodule",
version="1.0",
description="This is mymodule",
author="Me",
classifiers={
    'Development status :: 5 - Production',
    'Intended Audience :: My friends',
    'Topic :: Research tools'
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5'
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6'
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7'
},
packages=find_packages(),
python_requires='>=3.5, <4',
install_requires=['mymodule @ C:/mymodules/mydependency/mydependency.tar.gz', # <----
dependency_links=dependency_links,
)
```

However, it states that the URL is invalid:
"'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid URL given"

I have also tried including the path in dependency-links without resolving the problem.

I have search both stakcoverflow and the official documentation, but found no way around this.

Is it possible to include a localt tar.gz file as dependency? And in that case how should it be structured in the setup file.

Comment: I think you might need to add a `file://` prefix. So maybe `'mymodule @ file:///C:/mymodules/mydependency/mydependency.tar.gz'`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

Comment: I have just tried it, but it still gives the error :"Invalid URL given". Based on the source you provide, however, your suggestion seems right, perhaps I am doing it wrong at my end, but thank you for the response.

Comment: One additional thing: don't do `path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py install` or `path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py develop`, instead one should use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install path/to/project` or `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --editable path/to/project`.

Comment: I found it works - there was a "/" to much after file:. Thank you for assistance. If you post it as an answer, i will mark it and give an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references), such direct references require a `file://` prefix. In that case I believe it could look like the following:

```
'mymodule @ file:///C:/mymodules/mydependency/mydependency.tar.gz'
```

**Note:**

As far as I know, this notation is not supported by *setuptools*, in the sense that one can not use `path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py install` or `path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py develop` but should use *pip* (or probably any other modern installer) instead, for example like this:

- `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install path/to/project`
- `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --editable path/to/project`